# Perl copying files from one directory to another

Tags: perl

I'm trying to copy files from multiple directories with the code bellow. It prints out the correct path and files but fails to copy them. Please suggest how to fix this issue? Thanks

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

my $target_dir = "";

my @dirs = grep { -d } glob '/data/results/*';

for my $source_dir ( @dirs ) {

   opendir(my $DIR, $source_dir) || die "can't opendir $source_dir: $!";  
   my @files = readdir($DIR);

   print "the directory is $source_dir\n";
    my $run_folder = (split '/', $source_dir)[3];
    print "the folder is $run_folder\n";

   $target_dir = "/data/backup/$run_folder";
   print $target_dir;

   foreach my $t (@files)
   {
      if(-f "$source_dir/$t" ) {
         #Check with -f only for files (no directories)
         print "$source_dir/$t";
         print "$target_dir/$t";

         copy "$source_dir/$t", "$target_dir/$t";
      }
   }

   closedir($DIR);

}
```

Comment: `"/data/backup/$run_folder"` is relative to the root of the filesystem. Did you mean to make it relative to the current directory instead? Copying to the root of the filesystem probably requires elevated privileges.

Comment: I thought that Perl automatically created a directory if it didn't exist but I was wrong. I've added ` mkdir $target_dir;` and it fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things I would recommend you to do:

Close your file handles as soon as possible if you are not using it anymore:

```
   opendir(my $DIR, $source_dir) || die "can't opendir $source_dir: $!";  
   my @files = readdir($DIR);
   close ($DIR);
```

As you are trying to backup some files and directories maybe the target destination will not have the directory so:

```
 $target_dir = "/data/backup/$run_folder"; 
 print $target_dir;

 if ( ! -d $target_dir ) 
 { 
   #creates the dir
 }
```

And the last one:

```
   foreach my $t (@files)
   {
      chomp $t; # it removes any new line
      if(-f "$source_dir/$t" ) {
         #Check with -f only for files (no directories)
         print "$source_dir/$t";
         print "$target_dir/$t";

         if ( ! copy "$source_dir/$t", "$target_dir/$t" )
         {
            print "Some error: $!";
         }


      }
   }
```

Always TIMTOWTD, you could use File::Find which has a simple tutorial [here](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=217166).

Comment: https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy#RETURN *All functions return 1 on success, 0 on failure. $! will be set if an error was encountered.*